# Unrecognized selector error

Tags: ios

I am getting this error:  [NSURL stringByAppendingFormat:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5869210 when it gets to the append.  strcust is a plain number and strURI is correct until the append.

```
 NSString *strUIR = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://cid.hooru.mobi:36610/?";
 strURI = [strURI stringByAppendingFormat:@&Cust=IPRR%@", strCust];
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  I am just trying to append Name/value pairs from variables.  Can't get the append to work.

Comment: Theres syntax errors in the code you provided.  The first line is missing a closing square bracket. The second line is missing an opening quotation mark right after the @ sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with this piece of code:

1. You're declaring an `NSString` but you are assigning an `NSURL`
2. You're missing a right square bracket ']'
3. You're missing a double quote on your second line
4. You're trying to call an `NSString` method on an `NSURL` object
5. You're misspelling `strURI` on your first line (it is `strUIR`)

Try this:

```
NSString *strURI = @"https://cid.hooru.mobi:36610/?";
strURI = [strURI stringByAppendingFormat:@"&Cust=IPRR%d", strCust]; 
//Note the %d (if strCust is an int. If it's an NSString use %@)

NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL UrlWithString:strURI];
```

Comment: might want to edit this answer slightly. second line after the bracket, change it from strURI to strUIR

Comment: @JustinAmberson Thanks, just noticed it on the post and made a 5th point but forgot to edit mine as well :P

Comment: Yes, sorry, noticed these DUMB errors AFter I posted.  Looking at this stuff too long!  Thanks for fantastically quick response.

Comment: @MonicaRoseMartino You're welcome. If that was the answer you were looking for, consider marking it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

[NSURL URLWithString:] returns pointer of type NSURL. Merely collecting the return value that is NSURL* type in NSString* type does not convert it to NSString* type. Therefore strUIR is NSURL* type, even though declared as NSString *strUIR, and hence you cannot pass any message to strUIR that is supposed to be passed to NSString* type.

Answer (score 0):

NSURL doesn't respond to stringByAppendingFormat:

You specify strURI as an NSString so the compiler won't raise a warning, but you set it to an NSURL.

Either initialize the full string before creating the NSURL, or use URLByAppendingPathComponent:, I would recommend the first option.

```
    NSString *path = @"https://cid.hooru.mobi:36610/?"
```

...

```
    path = [path stringByAppendingFormat:@"&Cust=IPRR%@", strCust];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path]
```

For more information, see the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html